# Web-based fax service that does not reveal itself to be web-based on each page faxed

Tags: web-apps, fax

Most web-based fax services have "www.acmeonlinefaxes.com" URL on each page faxed.  I want to appear professional and have the faxes look like they came from a real fax machine.  I do not send many faxes each month.  So a high cost per page faxed would be acceptable.  The important part is that each page have no indication that it was sent from a web-based service.  I would rather not spend much money on this service, so the cheaper the better.

Comment: Which country are you in and which countries are you sending faxes to? It makes a difference to both cost and availability.

Comment: I live in the U.S.  I will send faxes to other U.S. locations.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different services that offer this on their **paid** plans but not all of them actually mention the "Watermark" or service advertising on their web sites. The majority of unpaid plans get their payback by advertising the fact that they are providing the service.  The best general advice is to contact the sales department, by email, to get confirmation that you will have full control over any content - *I say by email so if it turns out the sales person was "misinformed" you have some come back*.

Features to look for:

- No Adverts on your sent faxes
- Number of pages included in your plan
- Charge rate if you exceed your page count
- Geographic restrictions
- Any service or standing charges
- Email Gateway *lets you send faxes with any email client*
- Possibly Office Integration (Lets you print to a fax number or numbers)
- Provides you with a fax number for replies
- Allows you to select a geographic location for **your** fax number that minimises the costs to your clients/contacts - some services offer a toll free number but be aware that **you** will cover the costs.
- Personally I would look for a service which allows you to take your number with you if you decide to leave them due to service levels or pricing changes - another question for that email to sales.

One such service that I have used is [MyFax](http://www.myfax.com/faqs.aspx) which offers a good service, for $10 per month in the USA, but please shop around and contact the sales department as above.

***I do not currently, and never have, work for a company that provides online fax services to the best of my knowledge or my direct involvement.***

Answer (score 1):

There are many online companies that offers paid services for online fax but having all old technology and old features. Recently I used online fax service by [**faxitfast**](http://www.faxitfast.com/online-fax-features) with advanced features. Even you can use smartphone for this service.